# This would have been unthinkable last year

Tags: grammar

What is the use of "would have been" there? Is it still **a third conditional**?

> This **would have been** unthinkable last year, when North Korea was
>   launching missiles and testing nuclear devices.
>
> Today, we see growing acceptance of gay marriage - something that
>   **would have been** unthinkable a generation ago.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unthinkable
http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/19/sn.01.html

Comment: I'm not sure all those "numbered conditionals" are worth knowing about (only non-native speakers ever seem to be taught stuff like that, but I don't think knowing which number category a context falls into is much help in deciding how to express it). In your context there wouldn't be any significant difference in meaning if you replaced ***would have been*** by plain ***was*** (which native speakers would often.do).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree with that completely. There is in the idea of **would have been** the idea of: **had it not been for x**. We don't know what **this** refers to, therefore, we don't know what condition or conditional state the author is referring to. It can safely be said in general: Had it not been for some [state or condition], **this would have been unthinkable when North Korea was launching its missiles**.

Comment: Conditionals are an important part of the human imagination. Let's not do away with  them so blithely.

Comment: @Lambie: *I certainly **would not wish to** do away with conditionals so blithely.* But honestly, if you changed every one of the 351 written instances of [***would have been** unthinkable a century ago*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22would+have+been+unthinkable+a+century+ago%22) to plain [***was** unthinkable a century ago*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+unthinkable+a+century+ago%22) (130 hits), I doubt there would be a single case where this had any effect whatsoever on the meaning.

Comment: ...but of course, there could be a *huge* difference between *would have been **unacceptable** a century ago* and ***was** unacceptable a century ago*. And yet many people would say that in many contexts, ***unthinkable*** and ***unacceptable*** could be considered "synonymous".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can try and prove anything at all. The point is that **would have been [whatever]** simply does not **mean** semantically or grammar-wise what **was or was not x** mean. It changes the tone of what is being said. "It would have been difficult for him to pass the test" is not "It was difficult for him to pass the test"

Comment: We could boil that sentence down to "no one think x last century" and native speakers would understand. Since the goal here is to better our understanding of English, sweeping hard questions under the rug by saying, "native speakers would get it", seems very counter-productive.

Comment: Who cares about what native speakers understand? That's really not the point.

Comment: Same ole same ole. You're entirely focused on what you see as "syntactic logic" and "accurate grammar". But if a concept is/was *unthinkable*, you can't ignore the ***semantics*** - there's simply no meaning to the idea of distinguishing what *was* unthinkable from what *would be* unthinkable in OP's cited context, which is why it was so easy for me to find many examples showing that they're used interchangeably here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, agree but that was hardly the OP's question though. OP asked you why tires have writings on them and you replied, "Tires and tyres are the same word." Valid but entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is a huge difference between what would have been unthinkable and what was unthinkable. Verbal forms convey different meanings.

Comment: @urnonav: I don't know what that *tyre/tire* stuff is about. My first comment here simply reflects what I've picked up from retired linguistics prof John Lawler, who says on ELU: [***three** (or four, or five, or however many) conditionals ... is nothing but a 'baby rule' employed as a pedagogic tool to get you involved in conditional constructions*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/186953/2637). And his final advice in that answer is ***Stoutly abjure the trinity*** (even if you don't want to go *that* far, obviously he's advising against getting too bogged down in such categorisation).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the OP's question was to identify a given structure's underlying grammatical category. While saying that categorisation is not useful may be accurate - and I will agree with you on it to some extent - that is a non-sequitur here. Native speakers are frequently not taught much grammar at all. Their knowledge of language is experience-driven. The same method would not work for someone not immersed in English and that brings up all these formally taught structures, etc. I agree you do have to draw the line at some point and ignore some pedagogical artefacts.

Comment: @urnonav: Fair comment. You're certainly right about *Native speakers are frequently not taught much grammar at all* though. I've got a degree in English Language & Linguistics (admittedly, a long time ago now), but I've no idea whether the cited example (which *doesn't* explicitly include an ***if-*** clause) counts as a true ["third conditional"](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/third-conditional.html). But given the potentially significant difference in what exactly that "condition" implies, simply by changing ***unthinkable*** to ***unacceptable***, I doubt it's a useful label.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe either use-case is a conditional. There are no condition clauses in these sentences. A conditional use would involve a condition clause (if, had, unless, were, etc), such as:

> Had it not been for the civil liberties movements of the twentieth century, legalisation of gay marriage in the US would have been quite unthinkable.

In your example sentences, the modal verb "would" is used to express a habit at a different time. Here is some more information along with examples:

> ["We thought they would have got home by five o'clock, but there was no reply when we phoned."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would?q=would%2Bhave)
>
> [Expression of habitual aspect in past time, as in "Back then, I would eat early and would walk to school"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Will_and_would)

Essentially, you are expressing what was the norm/habit at a point in the past. "Would have" expresses a continued state of something. There is no condition here.

> Acceptance of gay marriage **would have been unthinkable** a generation ago.

This was status quo at that point. We are not conditioning this statement on any other fact.

Generally-speaking, the choice between "would have been", "used to be" and "was" depends on context, and is style-driven. With a word like "unthinkable" in particular, some may not see a distinction between the three. However, to get a sense of tonal difference, contrast with the following sentence:

> Even in the previous century, segregating priests of colour **was unthinkable**.

Here, the emphasis is on a single case that didn't fit the norm, so we use "was" instead of "would have been" or "used to be".

Comment: I think that every "would have been" [adjective] implies conditions. In both your examples, there is an underlying implication: had that been an issue and had that been tried, If fact, that would be the point of using that tense. Otherwise, one would just use **was**. For me, **would have been**, **used to be** and **was** are not stylistic at all. The convey different outlooks and meaningts...